# Show database users and their database objects with privileges

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to construct a query to display a list of users and each of the database objects that they have privileges.

I want my results to look like this:
[image: Users and the database objects and their privileges]

I am currently using pgAdmin 4. Can anyone help me on how to do this? i'd like to display the grants which have been granted to a specific user on different database objects.

Ex. john has SELECT, INSERT, etc. grants on database object table.

Comment: Okay, but what part do you have a problem with? Getting the data or displaying it?

Comment: What exactly do you expect "privs" to be for the columns "table" ? There are many tables in a schema, so to which table does that "privs" thing belong to? The same is true for "functions", "schema" or "sequences" - if there is more then one, what do you expect to see there?

Comment: i'd like to get the given grants for a specific user in each of the database objects and display them in a single table..

Comment: Again: what do you want to see in the "table" column if you have 100 tables in a schema?

Comment: the query would show each users grants to each of the available tables.. so if there are 100 tables then the query would show the grants of each users to each of those tables